# Remove entire JSON object if it contains a specified phrase (from a list in python)

Tags: python, json, list, object

Have a JSON file output similar to:

```
{
   "object1": {
      "json_data": "{json data information}",
      "tables_data": "TABLES_DATA"
   },
   "object2": {
      "json_data": {json data information}",
      "tables_data": ""
   }
}
```

Essentially, if there is an empty string for `tables_data` as shown in `object2` (eg. `"tables_data": ""`), I want the entire object to be removed so that the output would look like:

```
{
   "object1": {
      "json_data": "{json data information}",
      "tables_data": "TABLES_DATA"
   }
}
```

What is the best way to go about doing this? Each of these objects correspond to a separate index in a list that I've appended called `summary[]`.

Comment: In what context should the object be removed?  From the json file itself, or the in-memory python dictionary after reading from the json file?

Comment: From the json file itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, you could iterate through the JSON dictionary and test the `tables_data` values, adding the `objectX` elements to a new dictionary if their `tables_data` value passes the test:

```py
new_dict = {k: v for k, v in json_dict.items()
            if v.get("tables_data", "") != ""}
```

If your JSON `objectX` is stored in a list as you say, these could be processed as follows using a list comprehension:

```py
filtered_summary = [object_dict for object_dict in summary
                    if object_dict.get("tables_data", "") != ""]
```

Comment: This raises a RuntimeError in python 3 (dictionary changed size during iteration)

Comment: Yes, you're right. I have updated my answer to instead create a new dictionary using only the filtered elements.

Comment: My json information is all stored in a list so I don't have the '```items```' attribute

Comment: @weovibewvoibweoivwoiv Please show an example of your data structure in the question if it is not JSON or a dictionary.

Comment: Last line of my post indicates that I have a list called ```summary[]``` that holds my JSON information. Essentially, each object corresponds to a different item in the ```summary``` list

Comment: @weovibewvoibweoivwoiv See my update about using a list comprehension to filter your `summary` list.

Comment: @weovibewvoibweoivwoiv your code snippets shows a dict of dicts, there's no list anywhere.

Comment: @dspencer Python also have dict comprehension (cf my answer) ;-)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I'm just trying to address the fact that the dictionaries are apparently stored inside a list...

Comment: @dspencer that was about your first solution (the "dict of dicts" based one)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Okay, sure - updated to use a dict comprehension

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have compelling reasons to do otherwise, the pythonic way to filter out a list or dict (or any iterable) is not to change it in place but to create a new filtered one. For your case this would look like

```
raw_data = YOUR_DICT_HERE_WHEREVER_IT_COMES_FROM
# NB : empty string have a false value in a boolean test
cleaned_data = {k:v for k, v in raw_data.items() if not v["table_data"]}
```